# Method to count property of an Object linked to another property

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Lets say I have a file containing multiple planes and information about the planes structured as such :

```
type,max speed,name,color
commercial plane,750,boeing_777,white
private jet,800,cynthia,blue
propeller plane,200,venus,yellow
commercial plane,640,boeing_737,white
commercial plane,550,airbus,blue
propeller planes,150,tatoo,yellow
private jet,670,VLJ, white
```

From this I created the Planes class

```
public Planes{
    static int counter = 1;

    String type;
    int maxSpeed;
    String name;
    String color;
    int id;

    public Planes(List<String> element) {

        this.type = element.get(0)
        this.maxSpeed = element.get(1)
        this.name = element.get(2)
        this.color = element.get(3)
        this.id = counter;
        counter++;
}
```

I made several methods and now my objects of type Planes are in an ArrayList
My goal is to output a string which prints the type and the **number of *different* colors the plane type has**. So the output would be :

```
commercial plane,2 //2 because it has both white and blue NOT 3
private jet,2
propeller plane,1
```

I tried the following :

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayListPlanes.size(); ++i) {

        int it = 0;
        newList.add(arrayListPlanes.get(i).getColor());
        if(newList.contains(arrayListPlanes.get(i).getColor())) {
                it = it + 1;
            }

        String line += arrayListPlanes.get(i).type() + ", " +
                      Collections.frequency(newList, arrayListPlanes.get(i).getColor()) +
                      "\n";
}
```

The actual list is way longer and contains multiple other types of planes so I can't make an object for each types of plane.
I apologize for the badly written title

Answer (score 1):

Grouping planes by type with consequent collecting set of colors and re-mapping to the size of color set does the trick:

```java
static void countPlaneColorsByType(List<Plane> planes) {
    planes.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.type, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(p -> p.color, Collectors.toSet())))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> new StringBuilder(e.getKey()).append(": ").append(e.getValue().size()))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

However, there several points to be fixed in `Planes` class:

- rename to `Plane` as it describes a single plane
- fix compilation issues

```java
public static class Plane{
    static int counter = 1;

    String type;
    int maxSpeed;
    String name;
    String color;
    int id;

    public Plane(List<String> element) {

        this.type = element.get(0);
        this.maxSpeed = Integer.parseInt(element.get(1));
        this.name = element.get(2);
        this.color = element.get(3);
        this.id = counter;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    List<Plane> planes = Arrays.asList(
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("commercial plane", "750", "boeing_777", "white")),
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("private jet", "800", "cynthia", "blue")),
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("propeller plane", "200", "venus", "yellow")),
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("commercial plane", "640", "boeing_737", "white")),
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("commercial plane", "550", "airbus", "blue")),
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("propeller plane", "150", "tatoo", "yellow")),
        new Plane(Arrays.asList("private jet", "670", "VLJ", " white"))
    );
    
    countPlaneColorsByType(planes);
}
```

Output

```
commercial plane: 2
private jet: 2
propeller plane: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution based on the Stream API:

```java
// Group all planes by type
// key is plane type, value is list of planes
Map<String, Set<Planes>> plainsByType = planes.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.type));
plainsByType.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> String.format("%s, %d", e.getKey(), countOfUniqueColors(e.getValue())))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
    long countOfUniqueColors(Set<Planes> planes) {
        return planes.stream().map(p -> p.color).distinct().count();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use HashMap here for newList like below:

```
Map<Color,Interger> newList = new HashMap();
int it = 0;
if( newList.containsKey(color) )
{
    it = newList.get(color).value();
}
```

it++;
newList.put( color, it );